# Can I specify dataType in jsTree ajax call?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I need to specify `dataType: 'jsonp'` when making jsTree ajax call.

Can I do that? I didn't find anything in [jsTree site.](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, jsTree manual states that ajax config object is the same as jQuery so dataType property should work just fine.