# JQuery and XHR -- Cross-site JSON POST with CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jqxhr

I'm making a small UI to submit a JSON object to an external CastIron server (not that the server type is important to this question) using jQuery.  The initial send works fine, but I'm not getting the response from the server.  Here's what the jQuery looks like :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://cirun2/Impact/CreateImpacts',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(myobj),
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        //beforeSend: function(xhr){
        //      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        //},
        complete: function(returned_data) {
                $('#output').append("<p>Submitted successfully to CastIron. Returned data: " + returned_data + "</p>");
        },
        error: function(error_text) {
                console.log("Update unsuccessful. Status: ", error_text);
        }
});
```

I get the 'Submitted successfully to CastIron. Returned data: [object Object]' message, but it doesn't display the text, and firebug indicates that there's an error.

[image: Firebug response]

And here's the full error:

> "[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   http://server.company.com/mr/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js :: .send :: line
>   4" data: no]"

The part after the the 200 is the JSON object I'm expecting as a response.  I'm not sure how to get to it.  The part after the 'Via' is default CastIron headers showing how long each process took.  I'm not sure if these are getting issued in the wrong order, or what the problem is.

EDIT (7MAY2014): I've done some more poking around, and I think I left out a crucial piece of information.  I'm attempting to use CORS.  Here's my headers.  Is it possible that the headers are correct for the submit, but not correct for the returned value?

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  288
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 07 May 2014 14:34:51 GMT
X-Powered-By    Express

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host    myserver.mycompany.com:4000
Origin  http://ironsides.zayo.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
```

Comment: Unable to clearly view error message at posted image. If possible, can post error message text to original post ? Thanks

Comment: You need to use "jsonp" as datatype 
or try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157455/how-to-do-cross-domain-ajax-in-jquery-with-datatype-text

Comment: @guest271314 -  Sorry about that.  I removed the image and pasted the text.

Comment: Simple as pie: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) You are breaking it

Comment: @epascarello - The external server is able to receive my JSON object, does that mean anything?

Comment: Even if it were a same origin request, you should replace `complete` with `success`, since `complete` does not give you the data as a parameter, `success` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It ended up being improper headers from the CastIron server.  I had the CI admin fix the return code to '200 OK', and had her add the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *    
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
```

Turns out her response wasn't sending those headers.  After reading up on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and [Debugging CORS in Firebug](http://blog.dzhuvinov.com/?p=685), I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (pattern)

updated

```
$(function () {
    var callback = function (results) {    
        $("#output")
        .append("<p>Submitted successfully to server. Returned data: " 
        + JSON.stringify(results.caseURL) + "</p>")    
    };
    var myobj = {
        "caseURL": {
            "caseURL": "https://cs18.salesforce.com/50060000008ugtSAAQ"
        }
    };

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify(myobj)
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    });
    request.done(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        if (textStatus === "success" && jqxhr.responseJSON) {
            console.log(data, jqxhr.responseJSON, jqxhr.responseText);
            if (data.hasOwnProperty("caseURL")) {
                callback(data)
            };
        };
    });
    request.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error_text) {
        if (textStatus != "success") {
            console.log("Update unsuccessful. Status: ", error_text, 
            textStatus, jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
        };
    });
})
```

[**updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/xrEAQ/)

see

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings (`data`, `dataFilter`, `processData`)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server

Comment: Looks promising, but it's returning 'Update unsuccessful. Status: (an empty string)'.  The string I'm wanting is still after the 200 like it is in the screenshot.

Comment: If possible, can post request `url` ? Response from server `json` ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The URL is in my original code (`http://cirun2/Impact/CreateImpacts`), but is only accessible from our network.  The response I'm expecting is after the '200' in the console. It looks like this: `{"caseURL":{"caseURL":"https://cs18.salesforce.com/50060000008ugtSAAQ"}}`

Comment: 'Update uncuccessful. Status: ' (then an object that contains the statusText: `"[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://myserver.mycompany.com/mr/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js :: .send :: line 4" data: no]"`.  Same error as above.  It's catching the 'fail' condition.

Comment: I think I need to convert to JSONP.  I've emailed the CastIron admin to change what the reply looks like, and wrap it in a function call.

Answer (score 0):

The content type of a POST request is limited to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain for CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

See "Examples of access control scenarios">"Simple requests"

Please correct me if wrong.